# Return array append to input text

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I will send value type ajax but when data return come back will return json
How to append value to input text.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "find_data.php",
    data: "location=" + location_code,
    success : function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, values){
                $('#card').val(values.card);
         }); 
      },
    dataType: "json",  
    error:function(error){
            alert(error);
    }
});
```

Sorry for my english.
This is will show like this => 
[image]

Comment: share some HTML please

Comment: show us how your are printing the data in ajax call.

Comment: Also be careful about multiple id's in same webpage

Comment: include `console.log(data)`

Comment: Use `console.log(values.card);` after `$('#card').val(values.card);` line and check into console.

Comment: Just add this line :

`$('.card').value = values.card;`

Comment: If you dont want response in json then just comment the line `datatype: json`.

Comment: I have datatype: json.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=PmDtBzP7JF

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have an invalid markup as in having same IDs for multiple `input[type=text]` elements. The valid thing is IDs should be unique for each element or use a common class name.

If this is the case then i would suggest you to change the ID to class instead:

```
<input type='text' class='card'>
```

now in your ajax success you can change to this:

```
  success : function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, values){
         $('.card').get(key).val(values.card);
     }); 
  },
```

this line can be changed to this too:

```
$('.card')[key].value = values.card;
```

<sub>You have to post your markup for this, this case is my assumption.</sub>

---

#### What could be the issue?

If you assign same ID to multiple elements and when you make a selector of that ID, That always returns a single element in the page elements lookup. When lookup gets started and it finds the ID, it stops the lookup as per valid markup every element should have unique IDs.

Comment: Yes I have multiple elements What cand i do ?

Comment: I have multiple elements when return value And i wanna show multiple text box too.